# I need assistance with my USB Drive which is in 2 partitions, and I want to rejoin them into 1.

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, merge

So what happened is that my 32 GB USB Drive was initially 32 GB, more like 29.82, but still. Anyway, I use this for everything, school, personal, educational, everything. So then we recently got the DISH Hopper, and I noticed that I can plug in a USB Drive, so I backed up my 20GB of data on it, and the DISH Hopper box stated that in order to use the USB Drive with the cable box, I need to format it to a DISH Hopper-friendly format, so I let it do just that. Then I decided to format back to FAT32. but it says that I only have 1 GB of storage on the drive. So i decided to look at Disk Management, and it shows that it has 2 partitions, the 1GB portion, and a 28.82 portion.

I only have access to the 1GB portion in terms of standard point-and-click. I've tried everything I could in terms of using the Disk Management that was on my Windows 7 already.

I tried deleting the Volume on the 28.82 partition, and expanding the volume on the 1GB, but it did not let me.

When I used the Hopper to Reformat, on the Disk Management, it shows that they are both Primary Partitions, both healthy.

Can somebody help me recombine the 2 partitions into one, thank you.

If you have any further questions, please ask. I'll be happy to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the partitions and recreate a large one. You might be able to do that with Disk Management, or failing that try `diskpart` from the command line. [This guide](http://nlb-creations.com/2013/01/17/removing-partitions-from-a-usb-thumb-drive/) will show you how to do it that way.

Comment: **bold**THANK YOU!! THAT GUIDE WAS SO HELPFUL!! THANK YOU SO MUCH MAN. I'm new to this site, so if there is any way to give you a thumbs-up or something, I'll gladly do it. THANK YOU SO MUCH.